# Multivariate Distribution Question?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $(X,Y)$ have the following joint distribution:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2 f_X(x)f_Y(y) & \text{if }xy>0 \\[6pt]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

where $f_X(·)$ and $f_Y(·)$ are standard univariate normal densities

How to show $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$?

How to check if $(X,Y)$ jointly normal?

Please provide an informative step by step answer, I need to understand it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: They cannot be jointly normal if their support excludes two whole quadrants.  That can happen in a degenerate case where the support is just a line, but that's not what you've got here.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25890/same-joint-distribution-different-conditional-and-marginal-distribution/25919#25919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d/30205#30205.